# PHP 7.1 convert simplexml object to string

Tags: xml, php-7.1

I'm trying to build one of my first php procedure but I'm struggling on an apparently stupid issue and I need your help:

I need to load and modify an xml file and then I have to send via curl

here it is what I've done so far:

```
$userID='John';
$Action="Read";
$Quarter="2";
$xml=simplexml_load_file("test/xml/testxml.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xml->User->UserID=$userID;
$xml->Action=$Action;
$xml->Quarter=$Quarter;

$responseXml = sendHttpRequest($xml);
```

the problem, I suppose, is that sendHttpRequest requires $xml to be a string, while in my example it is an object
I'm quite sure about this since if I build the xml as a string..

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
$xml .= '<Request>';
$xml .= "<User><UserID>$userID</userID></User>";
$xml .= "<Action>$Action</Action>";
$xml .= "<Quarter>$Quarter</Quarter>";    
$xml .= '</Request>';
```

sendHttpRequest function works.

Therefore, hwo to transform $xml into a string?

I've seen some example using

```
(string) $xml-> ....
```

but these examples extract a node of the xml as string, while I need it fully.

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 1):

got it..

simpler as expected:

$xml=$xml->asXML();